# Min & Max values representation on graph in Highcharts or any other Library

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have to create  a graph representing Min and Max values in Highcharts but requirement is according to following image

[image]

Any suggestion is appreciable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best chart type to use in this case would be columnrange.

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'columnrange',
  },
  xAxis: {
    categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep']
  },
  yAxis: {
    min: 0,
    max: 2000
  },
  tooltip: {
    valueSuffix: '°C'
  },
  plotOptions: {
    columnrange: {
      borderRadius: '50%',
      maxPointWidth: 10,
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
      }
    }
  },
  legend: {
    enabled: false
  },
  series: [{
    data: [
      [1220, 1295],
      [1220, 1295],
      [1220, 1295],
      [1220, 1295],
      [1220, 1295],
    ]
  }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

**Demo**: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/sz20u8ce/ 
**API**: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.columnrange